# Div invading other div space?

Tags: html, css

I have no idea what's going on here. I have a div with two texts on it. And another div below - that works like a button. For some reason, this is happening...

[image]

Here is the code...

```html
<div id="container1" style="margin:auto;text-align:center;width:85%;">

  <span style="font-family:'Montserrat';color:white;font-size:55px;">PROFESSORES</span>

  <br>

  <p class="text" style="float:left;text-align:right;color:white;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Xxxx Xxxxx Xxxxxx</span>
    <br>&eacute; formada em psicologia e
    <br>especializada em ensino da
    <br>l&iacute;ngua inglesa, ambos pela
    <br>XXXX; morou na Xxxxxxx por
    <br>X anos, participou de v&aacute;rios
    <br>cursos na &aacute;rea de artes e
    <br>educa&ccedil;&atilde;o, culin&aacute;ria,
    <br>taichichuan, xxxxxxx,
    <br>t&eacute;cnicas de meditaç&atilde;o e hoje
    <br>é professora e coordenadora
    <br>de ensino da Xxxxxxxx.</p>

  <p class="text" style="float:right;text-align:left;color:white;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Xxxxxxx Xxxxx Xxxx</span>
    <br>é professora e tradutora de
    <br>espanhol e português, pós
    <br>graduanda em Gramática da
    <br>Língua Portuguesa pela XXXX,
    <br>cursos de formação para
    <br>professores de língua e formada
    <br>em Comunicação Social.
    <br>Amante do espanhol, não só
    <br>porque é a sua língua materna,
    <br>mas também porque adora
    <br>ensinar e compartilhar não só a
    <br>gramática como também
    <br>curiosidades, experiências,
    <br>cultura latino-americano e
    <br>espanhola, filmes, costumes,
    <br>expressões e receitas típicas.</p>

</div>

<br>

<div class="button">

  <span class="label">+ METODOLOGIA</span>

</div>
```

And this is the CSS code for the "button" class... as you see, there is apparently nothing that could interfere on the other div.

```
.button {

margin: auto;
background-color: #2C3254;
padding: 50px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px;
width: 60%; 

}
```

Comment: Where have you set the background color.. Also the issue has nothing to do with the HTML you have posted. Can you add more HTML?? Or better create a jsfiddle ..

Comment: Invader Div strikes again! XD

Comment: Ok, I added the CSS code for the button class there.. I forgot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to break from the floats. Since you're floating the two `p` elements, 'container1' is effectively as tall as the remaining elements (`span` and `br`) and the *button* div starts where the `br` is placed, much closer to the top than you expect.

You can use the style `clear: both` (that disallows content to float around the element) on the button and that should do it, e.g.:

```
...   
<div class="button" style="clear:both">
...
```

Or add a new `div` above it to act as spacer, whatever works best for you:

```
...   
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="button">
...
```

Comment: It worked! I honestly don't get it why I even needed to do this but it worked. Thank you outlyer.

Comment: @TomásDornasPerone With 'float:left' and 'float:right' set in the two content p's, their height is no longer part of the outer div, (try adding a border to container1 and you'll see it's as tall as the span and br), and the button starts directly where container1 ends

Comment: Understood. I've never seen such a thing happening with float. But I'm not experienced enough to opine. Hahaha

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult for me to check what is going on in the code you provided, so I have done something basic that you can add some css code, to make it look like what you are now working on.

```css
.div1{
 width: 380px;
 text-align: center;
}

.div1 p {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 187px;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.div2 {
 width: 380px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  
  <title>Collage</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="div1">
   <p>Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just textJust text Just text Just text Just Just text Just text  </p>
   <p>Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text Just text </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div2">
   <p>button</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a div invades another div, the problem is the div above the affected div has a negative `margin-bottom`.

This might help other specific cases with the same title as your problem.